# Что значит ошибка "No module named .." и как ее исправить?

Tags: python, модули

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from mechanize import Browser
  File "mechanize\__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from _version import __version__
ImportError: No module named _version
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интерпретатор не может найти модуль с именем `_version`. Убедитесь, что такой модуль действительно существует и что верно хотя бы одно из следующего:

- Модуль находится в той же директории, что и ваш скрипт.
- Модуль находится в текущей директории.
- Путь к модулю присутствует в переменной окружения `PYTHONPATH`.
- Путь к модулю присутствует в списке `sys.path`.

Comment: Я только поставил mechanize, никак его не использовал и не модернизировал, это какая-то вшитая ошибка mechanize?

Comment: Вряд ли. Этот модуль на самом деле существует: https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_version.py

Покажите, как пытаетесь его использовать.

Comment: 1. А остальные модули пакета работают?
2. Как вы его подключаете и где он расположен?

Comment: установил через cmd
Использовал так:
from mechanize import Browser

Comment: Ну оно ествественно у вас и не будет работать, после беглого изучения кода увидел, что импортируется класс **Browser** из файла **mechanize/_mechanize.py** где этой функции(_version) или класса нет, попробуйте 
import mechanize, а потом уже вызавать _version, а вообще методы класса Browser работают?

Comment: На import mechanize отвечает:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import mechanize
  File "mechanize\__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from _version import __version__
ImportError: No module named _version

Comment: И нет не работают методы:
x=Browser()
ОТвет:
no named Browser

Comment: Возможно, оно таки некорректно установилось, ибо из tarball'а прекрасно импортится:

    eigenein@eigenein-laptop:~/Downloads/mechanize-master$ python
    Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
    [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> from mechanize import Browser
    >>> Browser
    <class mechanize._mechanize.Browser at 0x7fbb0e65a6d0>
    >>>